# How to record WebRTC local video stream to file on Android?

Tags: android, webrtc

I have using WebRTC. I want to local video stream to file.
I'd appreciate it if you gave me a hint to approach this.

Thank you for reading it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //sigConnect("http://10.54.36.19:8000/");
    sigConnect("http://unwebrtc.herokuapp.com/");
    initWebRTC();

    Log.i(TAG, "VideoCapturerAndroid.getDeviceCount() = " + VideoCapturerAndroid.getDeviceCount());
    String nameOfFrontFacingDevice = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice();
    String nameOfBackFacingDevice = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfBackFacingDevice();
    Log.i(TAG, "VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice() = " + nameOfFrontFacingDevice);
    Log.i(TAG, "VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfBackFacingDevice() = " + nameOfBackFacingDevice);
    VideoCapturerAndroid capturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(nameOfFrontFacingDevice);

    MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

    VideoSource videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(capturer, videoConstraints);
    localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_ID, videoSource);

    glview = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glview);
    VideoRendererGui.setView(glview, null);
    try {
        rendereRemote = VideoRendererGui.createGui(0, 0, 100, 100, VideoRendererGui.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, true);
        rendereLocal = VideoRendererGui.createGui(72, 72, 25, 25, VideoRendererGui.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, true);
        localVideoTrack.addRenderer(rendereLocal);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream(LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID);
    mediaStream.addTrack(localVideoTrack);

}
```

Comment: do you find solution .?

Answer (score 0):

Libjingle library use GlSurfaceView for rendering video. You may try using FFMPEG library for saving video frames from that view. Not sure about audio though

Answer (score 0):

You have to create video container, like mp4, and manually encode and write every raw frame. Also the latest webrtc version, provides an access to recording audio from microphone. You should encode and mux audio samples as well.

- For accessing to raw video frames both, remote and local peers, see interface VideoSink. [apprtc/CallActivity.java](https://github.com/Piasy/AppRTC-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/appspot/apprtc/CallActivity.java) class ProxyVideoSink)
- For getting audio samples see class [RecordedAudioToFileController](https://github.com/Piasy/AppRTC-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/appspot/apprtc/RecordedAudioToFileController.java)
- For creating/muxing video files you can use [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer) class from Android SDK.